# How do I insert key frames at particular times with PiCamera?

Tags: raspivid

How do I insert key frames in a Raspivid stream not just periodically, but also at particular times, e.g., 0, 15, 30 and 45 seconds of each minute ? I want to do this so that breaking the stream into files gives files that always start at particular seconds. I don't want, for example, 15-second files that start at 7, 22, 37 and 52 seconds of each minute.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Raspivid documentation page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md):

> --intra,    -g      Specify the intra refresh period (key frame rate/GoP)
>
> Sets the intra refresh period (GoP) rate for the recorded video. H264
>   video uses a complete frame (I-frame) every intra refresh period from
>   which subsequent frames are based. This options specifies the numbers
>   of frames between each I-frame. Larger numbers here will reduce the
>   size of the resulting video, smaller numbers make the stream more
>   robust to error.

A sample command line to set I-frames at each 15 second interval (when recording at 25 fps) might look like this:

```
raspivid -g 375 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -t 10000 -b 3000000 -o test.h264
```

- `-g 375`: Set 375 frames between each I-frame (15 seconds @ 25 fps)
- `-w 1280`: width=1280 pixels
- `-h 720`: height=720 pixels
- `-fps 25`: 25 frames per second
- `-t 10000`: record for 10000 milliseconds/10 seconds
- `-b 3000000`: bitrate of 3000000 bits per second
- `-o test.h264`: output to file 'test.h264'

While, from the looks of things, your videos are going to be very short, I think I'd be inclined towards a higher I-frame rate if I were ever planning on seeking through the clips. Media players tend to 'snap' to I-frame intervals, meaning that your sub-divided clips will effectively be un-seekable. You could perhaps aim for 3 or 5 second intervals, which would still allow for accurate 15 second divisions.

Comment: Whoops! Cheers for the edit. :)

Comment: Thank you, but that procedure only sets the interval between I-frames, not the wall clock times at which I-frames occur. If I have key frames every 5 seconds, and I want video clips that are 15 seconds long, hence 3 I-frames per file, I want those video clips to start at 0, 15, 30 and 45 seconds of every minute. So I-frames need to be inserted at precisely 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ...55 seconds of every minute. How do I control the precise wall clock times of insertion ?

Comment: Aaaaaaaah. Gotcha. Goodness, that's *much* harder, and not achievable with plain old raspivid. Going to need some scripting I think. I'll see if I can come up with something sensible.